# NumPy for windows python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy

I can't find NumPy for windows python 2.7 although I found an OS X version of it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A Google search would tell you that its [`here`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.5.1/numpy-1.5.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download) .

Answer (score 2):

numpy-1.5.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe works for Python 2.7. I just installed and tested it with:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = arange(10).reshape(2,5)
>>> a
```

**Output:**

```
>>> array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```