# Which numpy library is compatible with python 2.7.9?

Tags: python, numpy

i have installed python 2.7.9 in windows 7 64-bit. When i open the python shell and write this command

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

I have the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

To install numpy, which package should i install? There are 21 items listed [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/). Which is compatible with python 2.7.9. What is the site to find that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NumPy for windows python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554277/numpy-for-windows-python-2-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Go to SF site [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/) for Numpy 1.9.2 and scroll down to file named numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
Download and install that one. Note that you might need to uninstall any numpy package installed (just to avoid any case of collision)